# Does such a test function exist?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Is there a nonnegative test function $\phi$ in $\mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that

1. $\Delta\phi(x/k)\to\Delta\phi(0) $ uniformly on bounded sets, as $k\to\infty$  ($\Delta$ is the laplacian)
2. $\Delta\phi(0) $ is not zero?

Comment: how can a function be in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: lulu. Sorry! Bernard. Thanks for correction. gty98b. This is a smooth function with compact support.

Comment: Any test function with $\Delta \phi(0)\ne 0$ is an example (PS: you are using $n$ in different ways)

Comment: But why the convergence whould be uniform?